# DELL extended monitor from Dell laptop by docking station

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, multiple-monitors

I have a DELL laptop connected to another DELL 23" HD monitor by VGA cable connected to docking station.

The resolution on the extended monitor is blur and the monitor driver detects PnP montor.

I have downloaded the DELL driver for the monitor it didn't fix the issue, and when I disconnected the monitor from the docking station for a week and connected it again it detected the driver and worked fine until I un-docked the laptop from the docking station and re-docked it again the issue with the drive came back again.

I asked for technical support they tried to fix it but they only could do is make the monitor detect the driver but this time when it detected the driver it was still resolution is blurry, so they told me that there is big chance that the graphic card it damaged or can't handle two monitors.

I even tried a different monitor it had the same issue so it means that the issue is not from the monitor!

Could anyone help I tried everything...

Details of the Laptop details, graphics card & Driver:

Laptop Details

```
Laptop model                 : Latitude E7240
Processor                    : Intel Core i7 -4600 2.10GHz 2.70GHz
Ram                          : 16GB
Windows                      : Pro 7 - 64 Bit
```

Graphics card

```
                             : Inter (R) HD graphics Family.
Total available Graphics card: 1824MB
Dedicated Video Memory       : 192MB
System Video Memory          : 0MB
Shared System Memory         : 1632MB
```

Driver Details

```
Driver Provider              : Intel Corp 
Driver Date                  : 4/8/2016
Driver Version               : 10.18.14.44:32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not a driver issue. Monitors in general don't need dedicated drivers.

You haven't told us exact monitor model, but it's a 23" one, so I guess its resolution is 1920×1080. That's way too much data for VGA to carry reliably. It's an analog video link, which means it's very prone to interference. Which results in a blurred image!

So my solution is: **Use a digital cable**, such as DVI, HDMI or DisplayPort. Dell E-Dock docking stations have DVI and DP outputs. DVI can also be easily converted to HDMI with cheap passive adapters, so you can basically get all kinds of digital video outputs from that docking stations. Check which one your monitor supports.

Comment: Yes, it was the VGA cable when I replaced it with HDMI it worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

We can try to troubleshoot the issue as below：

Try to connect the DELL 23" HD monitor directly to the laptop to see if the problem still exists.

If it doesn't exist, it may be a problem with the dock station.

If there is still a problem, try to download the Intel HD Graphics 4400 graphics driver to see if it works.